# How to machine learn (Tree) on several attributes?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, machine-learning, tree, scikit-learn

I am using python and scikit-learn's tree classifier in a little fictive machine learning problem. I have binary outcome variable (`wc_measure`) and I believe it is dependent on a few other variables (`cash`, `crisis`, and `industry`). I tried the following:

```
#   import neccessary packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn as skl
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts


#   import data and give a little overview
sample = pd.read_stata('sample_data.dta')

s = sample


#   What I want to learn on
X = [s.crisis, s.cash, s.industry]
y = s.wc_measure
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size = .5)


#let's learn a little

my_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = my_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = my_tree.predict(X_test)
```

I get following error: `Number of labels=50 does not match number of samples=1`. If I base `X`on a single variable (e. g. `X = s.crisis`) I am asked to reshape `X`. I don't fully understand why I have either of these issues... Ideas?

---

PS: This is the return of print(X)

```
[0     4.0
1     4.0
2     5.0
3     3.0
4     4.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     1.0
8     3.0
9     3.0
10    4.0
11    3.0
12    2.0
13    4.0
14    5.0
15    4.0
16    2.0
17    2.0
18    3.0
19    2.0
20    5.0
21    4.0
22    2.0
23    4.0
24    5.0
25    1.0
26    5.0
27    3.0
28    4.0
29    2.0
     ... 
70    1.0
71    4.0
72    4.0
73    1.0
74    4.0
75    3.0
76    4.0
77    2.0
78    2.0
79    5.0
80    2.0
81    3.0
82    5.0
83    4.0
84    4.0
85    5.0
86    3.0
87    3.0
88    4.0
89    2.0
90    2.0
91    3.0
92    3.0
93    4.0
94    3.0
95    1.0
96    4.0
97    2.0
98    3.0
99    4.0
Name: crisis, dtype: float32, 0      450.283417
1      113.472214
2       11.811784
3     1007.507446
4      293.895142
5     1133.297729
6     2237.830322
7     1475.787109
8      283.363678
9      626.888794
10      38.865730
11     991.999390
12    1115.746948
13     373.537231
14      97.570717
15     136.079193
16    2560.691406
17     667.062073
18    1378.384521
19     152.716400
20       5.779267
21     481.511566
22     677.809631
23     722.521790
24      32.927990
25    2504.450928
26      17.422865
27     651.585083
28     549.469177
29     297.458527
         ...     
70    1198.370239
71     471.343933
72     389.709290
73    2962.622803
74     581.519287
75    1148.822388
76      67.653664
77    1346.391602
78    1764.086914
79      14.308219
80     973.152161
81     552.576904
82       2.863116
83     425.520752
84     321.773682
85      63.597332
86    1351.122559
87     735.856567
88     745.656677
89    2784.453125
90    1438.272705
91     768.780823
92     827.021423
93     591.778015
94     885.169434
95    1143.088867
96     399.816803
97    1517.454834
98    1311.692505
99     533.062561
Name: cash, dtype: float32, 0     5.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     5.0
4     4.0
5     3.0
6     5.0
7     1.0
8     1.0
9     2.0
10    1.0
11    5.0
12    2.0
13    4.0
14    6.0
15    2.0
16    6.0
17    2.0
18    5.0
19    1.0
20    3.0
21    4.0
22    2.0
23    6.0
24    4.0
25    4.0
26    3.0
27    3.0
28    5.0
29    1.0
     ... 
70    2.0
71    4.0
72    3.0
73    6.0
74    6.0
75    5.0
76    1.0
77    3.0
78    5.0
79    4.0
80    2.0
81    3.0
82    2.0
83    5.0
84    3.0
85    5.0
86    5.0
87    4.0
88    6.0
89    6.0
90    4.0
91    3.0
92    4.0
93    6.0
94    3.0
95    2.0
96    3.0
97    4.0
98    6.0
99    4.0
```

---

PPS: Here is how I generate the data in Stata:

```
clear matrix
clear all
set more off

set obs 100
gen id = _n


*Basics
    gen industry = round(runiform()*5+1)
    gen activity = round(runiform()*5+1)
    gen crisis = round(runiform()*4+1)
        egen min_crisis = min(crisis)
        egen max_crisis = max(crisis)
        gen n_crisis = (crisis - min_crisis)/(max_crisis-min_crisis)

*Company details
    gen staff = round((0.5 * industry + 0.3 * activity - 0.2 * crisis) * runiform()*100+1) 

    gen revenue = (0.5 * industry + 0.2 * activity - 0.3 * crisis ) * 1000 + runiform()
        replace revenue = 0 if revenue<0

    *Working Capital (wc)
    gen stock = runiform()*0.5*crisis*revenue
    gen receivables = runiform()*0.5*crisis*revenue
    gen payables = runiform()*-0.5*crisis*revenue
        replace payables = 0 if payables < 0
    gen wc = stock + receivables - payables 
        egen avg_wc = mean(wc), by(industry)


    *Liquidity
    gen loan = (0.5 * industry + 0.2 * activity - 0.3 * crisis ) * 1000 + runiform()
        replace loan = 0 if loan<0
        egen pc_loan = pctile(loan), p(0.2) by(industry)
        replace loan = 0 if loan<pc_loan

    gen current_debt = n_crisis * loan + runiform()*100

    gen cash = (1-n_crisis)*revenue + runiform()*100


*Measures

    *WC-measure (binary)
        gen wc_status = (wc-avg_wc)
            egen max_wc_status = max(wc_status), by(industry)
            egen min_wc_status = min(wc_status), by(industry)
            gen n_wc_status = (wc_status - min_wc_status) / (max_wc_status-min_wc_status)
    gen wc_measure = round(n_wc_status)
```

Comment: Can you share sample_data.dta file?

Comment: Is X correct input for tts?

Comment: I can't share it. But I will upload a sata script showing how I created the data.

Comment: @Xevaquor see above for the data :)

Comment: @RachelSleeps unfortunatelly I am not able to use Stata, please add lines `print(s)`, `print(X)` and print(X.shape) and share output.

Comment: @Xevaquor I adde the output of `print(X)` to the question above. Returning the entire output of `s` went beyond the scope of Stackexchange's editor, yet I can tell you that it returns `[100 rows x 23 columns]`. `print(X.shape)` unfortunately left me with the following error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. The problem was that I did not define my sample `s` as an array - correspondingly, `X` was a list. Thanks everybody for helping out!

Here is what I did:

```
#   import data and give a little overview
sample = pd.read_stata('sample_data.dta')
s = sample
print(s.shape)


#   Have some mor vars and an array of explanatory vars


X = np.array((s.crisis, s.cash, s.industry)).reshape(100, 3)
y = np.array(s.wc_measure)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size = .8)


#let's learn a little

my_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = my_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = my_tree.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether X is correct input for tts? X has three rows and N  columns. X should have N row with 3 attributes. That's is why it complains the number does not match.

Comment: I dont't really get this as of now. I am completely new to python. I assumed the data structure of X to N-row/3-col. How do I check?

Comment: It should look like array([ [1,2], [3,4], [5, 6], [7, 9] ]). This array has two columns and four rows.  Please have a look at here. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html  There is an example of train_test_split. Hopefully this will help

Comment: Thank you! I know how to print the first few rows etc. but how do I get an understanding of the arrays structure?

Comment: When you read data using sample = pd.read_stata(..), you can use sample.shape to check dimension, something like sample.shape. In addition, when you do not know what functions can be used for a certain object, you can use dir(smaple) to see what functions has been built (you may already know this).